# Joining two tables django newbie qustion

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

mysqllite table joining in django is new to me. I can query just fine on one table. and somewhat at joining via just raw mysql.  What i need is an example of how to code to tables together Ie below the models and the first qustion on my project is to find all the teams that are in Atlantic confrence

I have 
    this in view

```
  "atlanticsoccer": League.objects.filter(name__contains="atlantic")

 this in html
    <h5>Question 1</h5>
                {% for whatever in atlanticsoccer %}
                <li>{{whatever.name}}</li>
                <li></li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ol>

which gives me all my Atlantic conference leauges. But i can't seem to find an example of how to join the teams by id . I have linked below the models view If i can get an example of how to do the first I can figure out the html. Thanks in advance for helping a new coder.

Models.py 

from django.db import models

class League(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Team(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, related_name="teams")

class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    curr_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="curr_players")
    all_teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team, related_name="all_players")

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import League, Team, Player

from . import team_maker

def index(request):
    context = {
        "leagues": League.objects.all(),
        "teams": Team.objects.all(),
        "players": Player.objects.all(),

        "atlanticsoccer": League.objects.filter(name__contains="atlantic")


    }
    return render(request, "leagues/index.html", context)

def make_data(request):
    team_maker.gen_leagues(10)
    team_maker.gen_teams(50)
    team_maker.gen_players(200)

    return redirect("index")

index.html

    <h5>Question 1</h5>
        {% for whatever in atlanticsoccer %}
        <li>{{whatever.name}}</li>
        <li></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get all `teams` that have a `league` with a name of "atlantic":

```
atlanticsoccer = Team.objects.filter(league__name__contains='atlantic')
```

Then iterate through them in your template and print whatever you want:

```
<ul>
    {% for team in atlanticsoccer %}
        <li>{{team.location}}</li>
        <li>{{team.team_name}}</li>
        <li>{{team.league.name}}</li>
        <li>{{team.league.sport}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Ty that is the example i was looking for now i can do the rest.

Comment: Way to go my friend. Happy coding!

Comment: if your still there yes this pulls all the data i need is there a trick to just pulling  the teams from a certian sport and league?

Comment: Of course. Try this: `Team.objects.filter(league__name__contains='atlantic', league__sport__contains="some_sport")`

Comment: Thanks again Ill figure out the html. Appreciate the help